# How to properly redirect in Laravel, with changing verb?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I'm coping some code from example inertia.js project, I copied organization put route, make action only return

```
return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Organization updated.');
```

In the JS I just made request

```
this.form.put(`/organizations/1`)
```

In the Network I see two responses - first "/organizations/1" with 302 code and second - to my "/apples" route with error

```
"The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST."
```

What I need to do to redirect my request with "get" verb, not "put"?

Comment: I think you should redirect to a route instead using `back()`. Eg.: `return Redirect::route('organizations.index')->with('success', 'Organization updated.');`

Comment: This isn't an issue with `Redirect()::back()`, you're trying to `PUT` to a URL that doesn't support it. I don't work with `inertia`, but can you do `this.form.post()`? Redirects are `GET` requests, so that code should work fine.